# gstreamer 1.x clockoverlay h264 won't show clock

Tags: overlay, gstreamer, h.264

I have working pipe with interpipe:

```
gstd-client pipeline_create recording_pipe interpipesrc name=rec_intpsrc listen-to=cam_src is-live=true allow-renegotiation=true enable-sync=false format=time ! queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=downstream flush-on-eos=true ! imxvpuenc_h264 bitrate=4096 ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location=/tmp/rec_%03d.mpg max-size-time=60000000000 max-files=4 muxer=mpegtsmux
```

Now I want to overlay clock but can't achieve it. Tried many variants like:

```
gstd-client pipeline_create recording_pipe interpipesrc name=rec_intpsrc listen-to=cam_src is-live=true allow-renegotiation=true enable-sync=false format=time ! queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=downstream flush-on-eos=true ! clockoverly ! imxvpuenc_h264 bitrate=4096 ! h264parse ! splitmuxsink location=/tmp/rec_%03d.mpg max-size-time=60000000000 max-files=4 muxer=mpegtsmux
```

Files are saved and managed but without overlay. As per reference I've got fully working stream:

```
gstd-client pipeline_create stream_pipe interpipesrc name=stream_intpsrc listen-to=cam_src is-live=true allow-renegotiation=true enable-sync=false ! queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=downstream ! clockoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc="Nimbus mono" valignment=1 ! textoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc="Nimbus mono" valignment=1 halignment=2 text="Live" ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! mpegtsmux alignment=0 ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=1234 sync=true
```

Any ideas ???

Comment: What does it mean "cant achieve it" ? What about running `gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! clockoverlay auto-resize=false ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=some.mp4 sync=true` on target device (where gstd runs)? Otherwise you should really check logs - rarely you get help with minimal info :)

Comment: I mean the files are recorded but w/o any overlay. For me is essential interpipe and splitmuxsink.

Comment: does the gst launch do something on target device? what about logs ?

Comment: In general your pipelines look correct.  You may need to reduce the issue to a pipeline you can fully post here.  If possible could you also check if the clock overlay works for basic scenaries like: `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! clockoverlay ! videoconvert ! ximagesink`?

Comment: As I said - that one works without problems: `gstd-client pipeline_create stream_pipe interpipesrc name=stream_intpsrc listen-to=cam_src is-live=true allow-renegotiation=true enable-sync=false ! queue max-size-buffers=3 leaky=downstream ! clockoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc="Nimbus mono" valignment=1 ! textoverlay shaded-background=true font-desc="Nimbus mono" valignment=1 halignment=2 text="Live" ! imxvpuenc_h264 ! mpegtsmux alignment=0 ! tcpserversink host=0.0.0.0 port=1234 sync=true`

Comment: That one shows video, but again not showing clock ???
`pipeline_create live_preview_pipe interpipesrc name=live_prev_intpsrc listen-to=cam_src is-live=true allow-renegotiation=true enable-sync=true ! queue max-size-buffers=4 leaky=downstream ! clockoverlay ! videoconvert ! imxg2dvideosink`

Comment: with log:
`0:00:00.528396013  2976 0x5694f830 INFO            gstdpipeline gstd_pipeline.c:398:gstd_pipeline_create:<GstdPipeline@0x75402270> Created pipeline "live_preview_pipe": "interpipesrc name=live_prev_intpsrc listen-to=cam_src is-live=true allow-renegotiation=true enable-sync=true ! queue max-size-buffers=4 leaky=downstream ! clockoverlay ! videoconvert ! imxg2dvideosink window-width=640 window-height=480 window-x-coord=800 window-y-coord=400"
`